# Wireshark expression filters for wireless capture

Tags: wireless, wireshark, pcap

1) What Wireshark expression filter stack can I utilize to discover how many devices are transmitting in the 2GHz and 5GHz spectrum in a packet capture?

2) What Wireshark expression filter stack can I utilize to discover the minimum (weakest) and maximum (strongest) signal strengths observed in a packet capture?

3) What Wireshark expression filter stack can I utilize to discover how many devices are transmitting on channel 6 (2437 MHz) in a packet capture?

Comment: Wireshark captures layer-2 *frames* which hold no information about the layer-1 details you're asking for.

Comment: @Zac67, most drivers capable of actually capturing 802.11 traffic insert radiotap information with each frame that contains data about channel/frequency and RSSI as these are very useful pieces of information.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may be better off with something like airodump-ng specifying a channel and optionally a bssid

```
airodump-ng -w file.pcap --channel 6 --bssid 00:11:22:33:44 wlan0
```

Answer (score 1):

for 1 & 2, well, you've got the wrong application for such a job. You can always capture packets with Wireshark. It hooks to an active interface and gives you insight about packets in transit.

But the tasks you want to do are more of signal analysis, rather than packet capture. That needs a WiFi-Analyzer. Search for suitable apps for you platform or Try any of:

```
wifi analyzer (android)
netstumbler (old)
inSSIDer
...
```

And for part 3 of your question:

```
airodump / airodump-ng
airopeek
airmagnet
kismet
```

Of course, the wifi adapter must also support some features to handle all the tasks some of these apps can do.